# How many four-engine commercial passenger jetliner types are currently in use?

Tags: multi-engine

Just heard following somewhere:

> It is easy to distinguish four-engine passenger jetliner type, because there are only three of them:
>
> - if it has "hump" upper deck then it is Boeing 747,
> - if it has two decks then it is Airbus A380,
> - otherwise it is Airbus A340.

Is this statement true?

I'm asking about commercial passenger jetliners only. So no cargo, no military etc.

Comment: Please clarify (by editing your post) what is the focus of the question: How many 4-engine airliners in the world? (title) or how to identify them? (body). I assume this is the latest, but without clarification, you may get answers to the title question.

Comment: Wonder if I'm the only person surprised there's so few aircraft in this list - I would have thought there were way more than a couple of single-deck four-engine airliners in common use.

Comment: @mins "How many... jetliner *types*", so I assume this is quite straightforward, right?

Comment: "*It is easy to distinguish four-engine passenger jetliner type... Is this statement true?*" is also quite straightforward, but not the same question. So do you want to know about the number or whether they can be distinguished easily (and optionally how)? Fortunately enough the selected answer cover both questions.

Comment: There's at least one more that's in use (albeit not very _common_ use), the Ilyushin Il-96, but that one's very visually distinctive anyways.

Comment: @Vikki-formerlySean The Il-96 is already mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Well, the 3 points you make are easily demonstrable to be true, and also a fairly unique feature of all three if looked at side-by-side.

The 747 is the only one with an obvious hump towards the front of the aircraft. This upper row of windows is unlike either of the other two

[image: 747]
<sub>Photo Aldo Bidini:: source: http://www.airliners.net/photo/Alitalia/Boeing-747-243B/1200648/L?sid=f499b3169d12a0d4f410846e6512443a</sub>

The A380 has an entire upper row of windows - it does indeed have 2 full decks.

[image: A380]
   <sub>Richard Vandervord source: http://www.airliners.net/photo/Etihad-Airways/Airbus-A380-861/2574151/L</sub>

If it has 4 engines, but neither a half upper deck and hump or a full upper deck (and it's an airbus!) then yes it is an A340

[image: A340]
<sub>Aero Icarus source: https://www.flickr.com/photos/46423105@N03/5445375360/</sub>

However, that is not all the 4 engine passenger aircraft.

The BAe 146 is a 4 engine regional airliner, and you could add to your distinguishing features "has a T-tail, must be a 146". It is also the only one of the bunch with a high wing.

[image: BAe146]
   <sub>Adrian Pingstone source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lufthansa.rj85.arp.jpg</sub>

And then we're into the Ilyushins. The Il-96, is easily distinguishable from the similar(ish) A340 as it is considerably smaller - hard to tell from a close-in photo, but in real life if one were parked next to the other the IL-96 is smaller.

[image: IL-96]
<sub>Anna Zvereva source:https://www.flickr.com/photos/130961247@N06/31268448486/</sub>

The Il-86 has 4 engines but does not fit your criteria, as it only remains in service with the Russian Military, but the Il-62 is still in commercial service. It's *very* easy to distinguish by having its 4 engines mounted on the tail

[image: Il-62]
<sub>Tim Rees source: http://www.airliners.net/photo/LOT---Polish/Ilyushin-Il-62M/1033235/L</sub>

Comment: The Ilyushin Il-96 is still in use.

Comment: The II-96 is easy to distinguish - it is so small, the size of an A320 or B737, yet with 4 engines.

Comment: @mins yes I guess so. Its just looking at pictures the scale is a bit hard to distinguish. If there was an A340 parked next to it I think it would be very obvious!

Comment: The Il-96 is more the size of a 767 than a 737 (if not larger). And of course there are still DC-8 and 707 variants in operation as well, maybe some Il-86 variants too.

Comment: @jwenting DC8 - 3 still in service, all cargo. No 707's still in airliner service. Travolta still owns one, but I dont think that counts! Il-86 I covered in answer (military only at this time)

Comment: @Jamiec: Your edit makes this answer a very good one!

Comment: Thanks @mins. I like this sort of question, thy're pretty benign but fun to research :D

Comment: For whatever it's worth, the newer aircraft from the BAe 146 family are known as Avro RJs instead.

Comment: The high wing of the 146 is a giveaway too.  And the IL-62 also has a T-tail.  Even with the sun behind them you're unlikely to confuse the two because of the different proportions.

Comment: @ChrisH Yeah, the high wing and the small size are the biggest giveaways for the 146. I don't think it would be very hard to tell the difference in size between a 146 vs. a 747, A340, or A380...

Comment: @reirab no, and when I needed to ID aircraft on approach (90s) they were among the smallest we saw. IL-62s weren't exactly common at LHR or LGW then either.

Comment: I'd distinguish the BAe146 by the fact that it's _tiny_ compared to the other planes. But the T-tail and high wing are also valid. :-)

Comment: @kevin the Il-96 is more the size of a 767 or A300 than a 737 or A320. It's a wide body airliner.

Comment: Are there any Vickers VC-10's still in commercial service?

Comment: @NeeravDodhia I highly doubt it. But if you find evidence to the contrary i'll happily add it in.

Comment: @Jamiec I'll have a dig when I get home from work

Comment: Regarding the Il-62, I'm not sure Air Koryo quite counts as _commercial_ service.

Answer (score 6):

You can add the [BAe 146](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Aerospace_146) to the list.

Comment: This should be a comment, or build a full answer for: "*It is easy to distinguish four-engine passenger jetliner type \[...\] Is this statement true?*"

Answer (score 5):

Boeing has B747 with 4 engines.
Airbus has A380 and A340 with 4 engines.
Antonov has an-124 with 4 engines and an-225 mriya with 6 engines.

Comment: While not very clear, the question is about distinguishing features of airliners with four engines. So how do you identify all of them?

Comment: @mins the question as written is about whether a statement that there are only 3 types of 4 engine jetliners is true, not how to distinguish them. So an answer stating there is a 4th type answers the question (no, the statement is not correct).

Comment: @mins the question text reads "Is this statement true?" so is about the statement, not the differences between other aircraft.

Comment: An-124 and An-225 aren't airliners and aren't in passenger service (question excludes cargo and military aircraft.)

Comment: As for clarity of my question, I agree. It could be much clearer. I must find some time to edit it to become a bit better. As for _reirab_'s comment, it is true. I was asking about passenger airliners and thus I had both Antonovs in my mind, but that's not what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 5):

Well... we should not forget legacy aircraft still in use. You might also spot some Douglas DC-8 still in use. [In this link](https://www.planespotters.net/production-list/Douglas/DC-8?sort=status) I have been able to find 8 planes still in use.

This figure [via wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Dc-8_landing_thule.jpg):[image]

In order to identify this old model just look to the engines, old fashion slim hets and look to the wing tips, there is no wing tip device.

Answer (score 3):

There's still John's 707 flying around - not commercially granted.
There's the VC-10 that could be confused with the IL-62. Only military now but was commercial.
And the Avro 85/100. Same but different from the BAe 146.
Bit too picky?

Comment: John Travolta returned to the Australian Historical Aircraft Restoration society (HARS) museum near Sydney. ref -> https://www.flyingmag.com/john-travolta-donates-his-boeing-707-to-australian-museum

Answer (score 2):

As stated in other answers, there are quite a few more 4 engined jet liners than just the three types stated in your claim.
Identification of the 747 and A380 is pretty simple indeed and correctly asserted in the claim.

Other types will all have their own characteristics, which would have to be found by studying photos and/or drawings of the aircraft in question (and possibly knowledge of which types can be expected at a specific airport, e.g. you're not going to find Il-62s in western Europe because they're banned there for noise abatement reasons).

Comment: IIRC, the reason commercial (or "commercial") Il-62 flights are banned in Europe is because they're operated by Air Koryo, rather than for noise reasons (the two remaining Il-62s in scheduled passenger service are both Il-62Ms, whose engines can be hushkitted to modern noise standards).

Comment: @Vikki-formerlySean no, the ban on Il-62 flights predates the dissolution of the Warsaw pact. In fact one of the reasons Interflug was looking to buy A310s was the impending ban on them using their Il-62s on flights between East Berlin and places like Amsterdam (they operated Amsterdam-East Berlin-Leningrad at the time using the type).